# How can i get this ng-option to init with selected object value?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I´m trying to start this select with a predefined option selected. But i need to use as value an object like you can see in my code. I need to get an id in data.selected.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{data|json}}
        <select ng-model="data.selected" 
            ng-options="p.id.another group by p.id.proxyType for p in proxyOptions" >
        </select>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.proxyOptions = [{
        id: { proxyType: 'None', another: 1 }
    }, {
        id: { proxyType: 'Manual', another: 2 }
    }, {
        id: { proxyType: 'Automatic', another: 3 }
    }];

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.selected = $scope.proxyOptions[0].id; }
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/fh01qndt/2/

**New Fiddle based on [Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678148/darren) comments**

http://jsfiddle.net/fh01qndt/5/

It works but i still need to specify the selected options this way:

```
    $scope.data.selected = {proxyType: 'Manual', another: 2};
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a sample scenario. my original code is far more complex. however what i need is to be able to set a complex object as value (in this case id). So this is correct:

   $scope.data.selected = $scope.proxyOptions[0].id;

but i can´t get the correct expression for ng-options.

Comment: You need to understand that you're not binding just the `id` - you're binding the entire `proxyType` object; that way you have access to all of it, not just the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$scope.data.selected = $scope.proxyOptions[0]` instead. Your way is creating another object which is different from your proxy options.

You just changed your questions code...Please don't do that.

Remove the .id from your assignment - ng-model will be the entire option object not just the Id

Here is your exact fiddle, but with the `.id` removed from your assignment. 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fh01qndt/4/)

**UPDATE**

Ok, So having looked again at your code I have tried to understand what you're trying to achieve - i also noticed that I misread your original JSON object regarding the `id` - sorry; i saw `id` and assumed it referred to "an id" and not an object..

However, I think what you're trying to do is set your selected option in code, so you would need to search through the list and find your match, no?

If that's the case, then this fiddle shows `ng-init()` calling a function to do just that.

Any good to you? [Another Fiddle, using ng-init](http://jsfiddle.net/fh01qndt/6/)

Comment: There is no way to deep compare objects?

Comment: Sorry about that... i need to get the id, instead of the entire object. Why i can´t improve the code of my question?

Comment: why would you want to deep compare? The use of ng-model here is to bind your seleted `proxyObject` to your `data.selected` - really don't know why you wouldn't use them correctly? and also, by editing your original question - rather than adding to it - you invalidate any answers given; the answers that people give suddenly make no sense if you edit the code in your question.

Comment: As i said, this is only a simplified scenario. i need to be able to edit the `id` property with a select menu. And all the available values come from another source. So `data.selected` will never be the same object compared to any `$scope.proxyOptions` element. However they are equals based on its internal properties. Thanks for your patience and helpful comments.

Comment: It doesn't matter that data.selected will never be the same. You're telling angular "give me a list please, and i want the datasource to be these `proxyOptions` - and of the options, I want the one to be selected to match 'this' (whatever 'this' is)" you cannot do what you think you're trying to do. `id` in your case IS a proxy option. So you might not want to use that particular `id` in this case ([0]) - so then build something to search in your options for what you DO want to be selected. I will put a fiddle to show you what i mean.

Comment: Thanks Darren! ng-init looks just as a great option for me. Also thanks for all the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

**IF U NEED ONLY THE PLEAE CHECK THIS ONE**

```
$scope.proxyOptions = {
    '1': 'None',
    '2': 'Manual',
    '3': 'Automatic'
};

$scope.data.selected = '1';

<select ng-model="data.selected" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in proxyOptions" >
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function DataController($scope) {
    $scope.proxyOptions = [{
        id: { proxyType: 'None', another: 1 }
    }, {
        id: { proxyType: 'Manual', another: 2 }
    }, {
        id: { proxyType: 'Automatic', another: 3 }
    }];
    $scope.data.selected=$scope.proxyOptions[0];
}
```

[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fh01qndt/3/)